# Exporting and importing images in MediaWiki

Tags: image, import, export, mediawiki

How do I export and import images from and into a MediaWiki?

Comment: Is is possible to get the URL of the image from sepcial:export or some way that is not "screen scraping"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no automatic way to export images like you export pages, you have to right click on them, and choose "save image". To get the history of the Image page, use the [Special:Export](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Export) page.

To import images use the [Special:Upload](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Upload) page on your wiki. If you have lots of them, you can use the [Import Images script.](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php) Note: you generally have to be in the sysop group to upload images.

Comment: Is it possible to add images manually through the command line using a simple drag-and-drop?

Answer (score 11):

## Terminal solutions

MediaWiki administrator, at server's terminal, can perform [maintenance tasks using the *Maintenance scripts* framework](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Maintenance_scripts). New Mediawiki versions run all standard scripts in the tasks described below, but old versions have some bugs or not have all moderns scripts: check the *version number* by   `grep wgVersion includes/DefaultSettings.php`.

Note: all cited (below) scripts have also `--help` option, for instance 
`php maintenance/importImages.php --help`

#### Original image folder

Users upload files through the Special:Upload page; administrators can configure the allowed file types through an extension whitelist. Once uploaded, files are stored in a folder on the file system, and thumbnails in a dedicated thumb directory.

The Mediawiki's `images` folder can be zipped with `zip -r ~/Mediafiles.zip images` command, but this zip is not so good:

- there are a lot of expurious files: "deleted files" and "old files" (not the *current*) with filenames as `20160627184943!MyFig.png`, and thumbnails as `MyFig.png/120px-MyFig.jpg`.
- for [data-interchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) or long-term [preservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_preservation) porpurses, it is invalid... The **ugly `images/?/??/*` folder format** is not suitable, as usual "all image files in only one folder".

#### Images export/import

For "Exporting and Importing" **all current images in one folder** at MediaWiki server's terminal, there are a step-by-step single procedure.

**Step-1:** generate the image dumps using *dumpUploads* (with `--local` or `--shared` options when preservation need), that creates a *txt* list of all image filenames in use.

```
mkdir /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles
php maintenance/dumpUploads.php \
   | sed 's~mwstore://local-backend/local-public~./images~' \
   | xargs cp -t /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles
zip -r ~/Mediafiles.zip /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles
rm -r /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles
```

The command results in a standard zip file of your image backup folder, `Mediafiles.zip` at yor user root directory (`~/`).

NOTE: if you are not worried about the *ugly folder strutcture*, a more direct way is

```
 php maintenance/dumpUploads.php \
   | sed 's~mwstore://local-backend/local-public~./images~' \
   | zip ~/Mediafiles.zip -@
```

according Mediawiki version the `--base=./` option will work fine and you can remove the `sed` command of the pipe.

**Step-2:** need a backup? installing a copy of the images? ... you need only `Mediafiles.zip`, and the [Mediawiki installed](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Installation), with no contents... If the Wiki have contents, check problems with filename conflicks (!).  Another problem is configuration of file formats and permissions, that must be the same or broader in the new Wiki, see [Manual:Configuring file uploads](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads).

**Step-3:** restore the dumps (**to the new Wiki**), with the maintenance tools. Supposing that you used step-1 to  export and preserve in a zip file,

```
 unzip ~/Mediafiles.zip -d /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles
 php maintenance/importImages.php  /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles
 rm -r /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles 
 php maintenance/update.php
 php maintenance/rebuildall.php
```

That is all. Check, navegating in your new Wiki's *Special:NewFiles*.

---

#### The full export or preservation

For exporting "ALL images and ALL articles" of your old MediaWiki, for full backup or [content preservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_preservation).  Add some procedures at each step:

**Step-1:** ... see above step-1... and, to generate the text-content dumps **from the old Wiki**

`php maintenance/dumpBackup.php --full | gzip > ~/dumpContent.xml.gz`

Note: instead of `--full` you can use the  `--current` option.

**Step-2:** ... you need `dumpContent.xml.zip` and `Mediafiles.zip`... from the old Wiki. Suppose both zip files at your `~` folder.

**Step-3:** run **in your new Wiki**

```
 unzip ~/Mediafiles.zip -d /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles
 gunzip -c  ~/dumpContent.xml.gz 
   | php maintenance/importDump.php  --no-updates \
   --image-base-path=/tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles
 rm -r /tmp/workingBackupMediaFiles 
 php maintenance/update.php
 php maintenance/rebuildall.php
```

That is all. Check also *Special:AllPages* of the new Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

***- Export ALL:***

You can get all pages and all images from a MediaWiki web using [API], even you are not the owner of the web (of course when the owner hasn't disable this function):

**Step 1**: Using API to get [all pages title](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages) and [all images url](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allimages). You can write some code to do it automatically.

**Step 2**: Next you use [Special:Export] to export all pages with the titles you got, and use `wget` to get all images you had links (like this `wget -i img-list.txt`).

***- Import ALL:***

**Step 1**: Import pages using [Special:Import]

**Step 2**: Import images using [Manual:ImportImages.php].

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mass upload tools available.

**Commonist** - www.djini.de/software/commonist/

Both run on the desktop and can be configured to upload to your local wiki (they are configured for Wikipedia and Wikimedia commons by default). If you are afraid to edit the content of a .jar file, I suggest you start with Commonplace.

Another useful extension exists for Mediawiki itself.

**MultiUpload** - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MultiUpload

This extension allows you to drop images in a folder and load them all at once. It supports annotations for each file if necessary and cleans up the folder once it is done. On the downside, it requires opening a shared folder on the server side.

**Commonplace** - commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Tools/Commonplace

used to be available, but it was [deprecated as of Jan. 13, 2010](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/wiki/Commons:Tools/Commonplace).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps a bit: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php

Answer (score 0):

As a committer of [MediaWiki-Japi](http://mediawiki-japi.bitplan.com/index.php/Main_Page) I'd like to point out:

For the usecase to push pages including images from one wiki to another [MediaWiki-Japi](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/Mediawiki-Japi) now has a command line mode see 
[Issue 49 - Enable commandline interface with page transfer option](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/Mediawiki-Japi/issues/49)

Otherwise you can use [MediaWiki-Api](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) with the language of your choice and use the functions as you find in [PushPages.java](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/Mediawiki-Japi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitplan/mediawiki/japi/PushPages.java)

e.g.

- [download](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/Mediawiki-Japi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitplan/mediawiki/japi/PushPages.java#L259)
- [upload](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/Mediawiki-Japi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitplan/mediawiki/japi/PushPages.java#L246)