# Export/Import images between mediawiki sites respecting history and metadata

Tags: mediawiki

I have to export new images and those images that have been edited from one wiki to another, the aim is that in the end the two wiki sites have the same images with the same history.

How can I do it?, I mean importing the images with the revisions and metada as for example, the user name or timestamp.

Using **`dumpUpload`** and **`importimages`** I only get the last version of the images and lost the metadata, it appears as maintenance import.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate or a similar question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002258/exporting-and-importing-images-in-mediawiki!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to export images like you export pages, you have to right click on them, and choose *"Save image"*.

To get the history of the Image page, use the **[Special:Export](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Export)** page.

---

To import images use the *[Special:Upload](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Upload)* page on your wiki. If you have lots of them, you can use the **[Import Images script](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php)**.

> ***Note:*** Your account generally have to be in the sysop group to upload images. You can only export & import everything manually but you can also *[create a MediaWiki bot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Bots)*!