# Simplest way to make a copy of images in a folder

Tags: export, mediawiki

There are a "hidden option" or **other Wikimedia tool** to do **a simple image export**?

I am using this **so complex** approach at terminal,

```sh
php maintenance/dumpUploads.php | \
   sed 's~mwstore://local-backend/local-public~./images~' > /tmp/localList.txt
mkdir ~/MyBackupFolder
cp $(cat /tmp/localList.txt) ~/MyBackupFolder
```

... some "XPTO option" to do direct

`php maintenance/dumpUploads.php --XPTO ~/MyBackupFolder`

with no `sed`...

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Why don't you just back up your image directory?

Comment: Hi @Tgr, the default folder structure of Mediawiki (with may subfolders) **is ugly**, and in a little-size or medium-size Wiki we can backup all in only one folder. "all in one" is also a standard way for data-interchange and "preservation backups"... The result of the `cp` command is "all in one". PS: when restoring with `maintenance/importImages.php` you also use "all in one".

Comment: Well, why don't you just back up your image directory into one folder then?

Comment: @Tgr yes I do, by the script that I show (there are a simplest way?)...  Perhaps the question is a suggestion to `dumpUploads.php` developers, to add an option for it :-)

Comment: `cp /path/to/wiki/images/?/??/* ~/MyBackupFolder`? (Same for `images/archive` if you care about deleted files.)

Comment: Also, [T75157](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T75157) (the `mwstore:` bug) was fixed in 1.28, so you can use `php maintenance/dumpUploads.php | xargs cp -t ~/MyBackupFolder` if you want to be future-proof.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr for the `xarg` suggestion and bug link... I am using `dumpUploads` of a Mediawiki *1.24.1*... For more contect, see this answer (you can edit because it is a wiki-answer) with all needs and workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8771896/287948